# In Jenkins, how can I configure the build to fail when error codes fall within the range of 206 to 599 in JMeter performance tests

Tags: jenkins, build, jmeter, failover

In Jenkins, how can I configure the build to fail when error codes fall within the range of 206 to 599 in JMeter performance tests.
i want the build to fail when any API from Jmeter test fails (throws error )
any http value from 206 to 599 build should fail

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following approach:

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which response code you want to validate
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def status = prev.getResponseCode() as int

   if (status >= 206 && status <= 599) {
       assertionResult.setFailure(true)
       assertionResult.setFailureMessage("Unexpected status code: " + status)
   }
   ```

   This will mark the sampler as failed if response code within the given range.
3. For failing the Jenkins build you can use [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-performance-plugin) which can mark the build as failed if response code falls into unexpected range.